# How to Change Autofill Url Link Suggestion in Brave?

Tags: brave

[image: typing 'so' word in the browser]

In this image, I'm typing 'so' in the url bar. It then autofills/autosuggests in 'soundcloud.com'. I want it to instead autofill with 'soundcloud.com/you/library'.

I know this can be done by entering 'soundcloud.com/you/library' multiple times in the browser. However, I want to be able to do this via settings or to be able to manually access any autosuggestions.

Comment: You usually get the full substitution if you have an existing bookmark. idk Brave at all, so idk if it adheres to this behaviour.

Comment: I bookmarked 'soundcloud.com/you/library' however it still doesn't autosuggests into it when typing 's', 'so', 'sou' and so on.

Comment: Mine sets bookmarks on the line below the auto-suggest, so you just tap the down arrow or mouse to it. I actually have a lot of 'sound' URLs, so I need to type more to differentiate. Others behave that way, though.

Comment: I guess in Brave, that's the case huh? Two down arrow taps before you could get the desired if you'd go with the bookmark solution.